# Google search Site with wildcard in its URL and multiple intexts

Tags: google-search

There is a website that has many images in the following style:

- https://www.website.nl/app/uploads/Image1.jpg
- https://www.website.nl/app/uploads/Image2.jpg
- https://www.website.nl/app/uploads/Image3.jpg

So, I tried to do is use a google image search to get them all in the results with the following:

```
site:https://www.website.nl/app/uploads/*.jpg
```

I then realised that doesn't work so I changed it to:

```
https://www.website.nl/app/uploads/*.jpg
```

I am not sure whether this will return all the images though as google has a limit and I am not sure whether google just searches for the url excluding the "app/uploads/" part.

Secondly, I am trying to test the OR operator in the intext function:

```
intext:"first|second|third"
```

So, ideally my search would be like:

```
(intext:"first|second|third" + site:https://www.website1.nl) | site:https://www.website2.com/
```

Is that possible? Searching one website and whether the pages returned contain specific values and then search another website at the same search?